# How to intersect 2 subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, node-sqlite3

Hello i want to intersect 2 long Queries with each other but i found out that you can only intersect simple Queries. Is this possible to get something like this?

```
SELECT id, name as antibodyName 
FROM Antibodies 
WHERE id IN (
           (SELECT id FROM Antibodies WHERE name LIKE ?
                   UNION ALL
            SELECT antiId FROM AssignedColors WHERE name LIKE ?
                   UNION ALL
            SELECT antiId FROM AssignedReactivities WHERE name LIKE ?)
         INTERSECT
           (SELECT id FROM Antibodies WHERE name LIKE ?
                   UNION ALL
            SELECT antiId FROM AssignedColors WHERE name LIKE ?
                   UNION ALL
            SELECT antiId FROM AssignedReactivities WHERE name LIKE ?)
)
AND dateOfCreation >= ? AND dateOfCreation <= ?
ORDER BY dateOfCreation DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

Actually i want to get Intersect of unions of other queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a `SELECT` statement for each group of your unioned queries:

```
SELECT id, name as antibodyName 
FROM Antibodies 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM
  (
    SELECT id FROM Antibodies WHERE name LIKE ?
    UNION all
    SELECT antiId FROM AssignedColors WHERE name LIKE ?
    UNION all
    SELECT antiId FROM AssignedReactivities WHERE name LIKE ?
  )
  INTERSECT
  SELECT id FROM
  (
    SELECT id FROM Antibodies WHERE name LIKE ?
    UNION all
    SELECT antiId FROM AssignedColors WHERE name LIKE ?
    UNION all
    SELECT antiId FROM AssignedReactivities WHERE name LIKE ?
  )
) AND dateOfCreation >= ? AND dateOfCreation <= ?
ORDER BY dateOfCreation DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET?;
```

Comment: is there any way to do multi word search in SQL? because i wrote this to do 2 words search

Comment: Multi word search like what?

Comment: For example if the user searches 'red 200' it should return antibodies which have red in their colors and 200 in their names and again if the user searches 'red 200 blue' it should return antibodies with color red and name 20 and color blue. I mean i want to search for each of these words and find the Intersect of all results.

Comment: If you are referring to the tables in your query there could be an easier solution, but I can't be certain without sample data and expected results. So post a question where you provide all of that to clarify what you want.

Comment: ok thanks i made the question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220018/how-to-do-a-multi-word-partial-search-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, an INNER JOIN would help solve the problem most efficiently. The inner INSERSECT can be changed to the below code, and the outer SELECT can remain the same.

```
(SELECT id FROM Antibodies WHERE name LIKE ?
UNION all
SELECT antiId FROM AssignedColors WHERE name LIKE ?
UNION all
SELECT antiId FROM AssignedReactivities WHERE name LIKE ?) A
JOIN
(SELECT id FROM Antibodies WHERE name LIKE ?
UNION all
SELECT antiId FROM AssignedColors WHERE name LIKE ?
UNION all
SELECT antiId FROM AssignedReactivities WHERE name LIKE ?) B
ON A.id = B.id
```